# Как остановить работу функции?

Tags: jquery, javascript

[Ссылка в песочницу](http://jsfiddle.net/Hancock_888/WyYUA/)

```
var preloader_fun = function() {    
      y = 21;
      var z = Math.round(1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000));      
      console.log("working ");   
      $(".js_preloader").stop(false, true).animate({height: '-='+ y +'px'}, z, "swing"); 
     setTimeout(preloader_fun,z);       
};

preloader_fun();

/*----------------------------------
 *  Есть замкнутая функция нужно ее остановить. 
 *  Как вариант остановка через пол минут, либо по принудительной остановке
 *  Для просмотра работы можно открыть консоль и увидеть что она работает - (число) "working  "
 *----------------------------------*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Механизм остановки:

```
var timer=setInterval(your_function,timeout);//запуск
clearTimeout(timer)//Остановка,выбирете по какому событию оно будет срабатывать
```