# Jquery. Подскажите как остановить выполнение функции в зависимости от chekbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь сделать плагин для визуального редактора.
Элемент для редактирования определяю среди всех элементов при помощи функции `$("*")hover`.

Хочу сделать чтобы можно было подсветить элемент при наведении, но только после активации checkbox(Режим редактирования)

Но проблема кроется в том что, я хочу чтобы данная функция работала только при нажатом Checkbox. А у меня после отжатия чекбокса функция продолжает работать и не останавливается.

Вот ссылка на полный код https://jsfiddle.net/Eusene/x002e7et/1/

Фрагмент скрипта:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        // Галочка стоит
        console.log('ON')
        //Запускаем редактор    
        $("*").hover(function(){ //Определяем элемент с hover
            $focusid = $(this).attr('class'); //Записываем класс элемента
            /*console.log($focusid);*/
            $(this).hover(
                function(){ 
                    $("*").removeClass('editfocus'); //Очищаем классы
                    $(this).addClass('editfocus'); //Выделяем 1 эл.
                    $focusHtml = $(this).parent().html();
                    /*console.log($focusHtml);*/
                    $("#editorHtml").val($focusHtml);
                },
                function(){ $(this).removeClass('editfocus') });
        });  // End.Редактор
    } else {
        // Галочка не стоит
        console.log('OFF')
        $("*").removeClass('editfocus'); //Очищаем классы
    }
});
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/237121/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберет обработку 'hover':  `$("*").off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave');`

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
            // Галочка стоит
            console.log('ON')
            //Запускаем редактор    
            $("*").hover(function(){ //Определяем элемент с hover
                $focusid = $(this).attr('class'); //Записываем класс элемента
                /*console.log($focusid);*/
                $(this).hover(
                    function(){ 
                        $("*").removeClass('editfocus'); //Очищаем классы
                        $(this).addClass('editfocus'); //Выделяем 1 эл.
                        $focusHtml = $(this).parent().html();
                        /*console.log($focusHtml);*/
                        $("#editorHtml").val($focusHtml);
                    },
                    function(){ $(this).removeClass('editfocus') });
            });  // End.Редактор
        } else {
            // Галочка не стоит
            console.log('OFF')
            $("*").off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave'); // вот тут
            $("*").removeClass('editfocus'); //Очищаем классы
        }
    });
```

Comment: Немного не понял можете разъяснить?

Comment: вместо `unbind` лучше использовать `off`, т.к. `unbind` объявлен как deprecated в версии 3.0. `off` поддерживается с jQuery 1.7

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Поставил бы плюс но нет возможности

Comment: $("*").off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave'); Так лучше?

Comment: @Arnial подправил)) Евгений, да))

Comment: @Arnial Как считаете данный плагин будет востребован или нет? Мне хочется чтобы плагин давал возможность редактировать всё в живую на ходу, и чтобы данный плагин работал не зависимо от CMS. Просто подключил библиотеку js и всё)

Comment: @ЕвгенийГурьев ХЗ. Думаю разработчики используют инспектор встроенный в браузер. Можно представлять как альтернативу редакторам в CMS, но боюсь для пользователей это будет сложно.